# operand should contain 1 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, phpbb, mysql-error-1241

```
SELECT topic_id
FROM phpbb_topics AS t
WHERE t.topic_id IN (
    SELECT p.topic_id, COUNT(p.post_id) AS total_posts
    FROM phpbb_posts AS p
    WHERE p.poster_id = 61640
    GROUP BY p.topic_id
    HAVING t.topic_replies_real = total_posts - 1
);
```

That query gets me the following error:

Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't include `COUNT(p.post_id) AS total_posts` in `SELECT` list in your subquery.
Just

```
SELECT topic_id   
FROM phpbb_topics AS t
WHERE t.topic_id IN (
    SELECT p.topic_id --, COUNT(p.post_id) AS total_posts 
    FROM phpbb_posts AS p
    WHERE p.poster_id = 61640
    GROUP BY p.topic_id
    HAVING t.topic_replies_real = COUNT(p.post_id) - 1
);
```

Comment: I am attempting to do the same style of statement but with a DELETE. Is there any way that I can SELECT multiple rows in my subquery? MySQL keeps throwing the 1241 Error at me.